How do I display an image in a Modal Window Shopping Cart (Javascript/Bootstrap)
I have used someone else's code as I am very new to Javascript.
I have managed to get the add to shopping cart functioning, displaying product title, price etc. but would like to add a small thumbnail of the product also.
I have managed to reference the product in the window - but I would like this to be an image and not text.
Html:
(product)
<div class="ParkingLightInner">
      <div class="SplitColour" style="background:#5a6064;"></div>
        <div class="Hover">
        <div class="ProductImg">
          <img src="img/Gen2/SingleMed.webp" data-img="img/Gen2/SingleMed.webp" class="Image" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Single Mid</h4>
                <p style="font-size:.7rem;line-height: .1rem;">14 Colour options</p>
                <p class="card-text">£47.99<span style="font-size:.6rem"> Inc p&amp;p</span></p>
            <div class="BuyGrid">
        <div class="SaveButton">
    <a href="#" data-name="Single-Mid" data-price="47.99" class="add-to-cart"><span style="color:#f26522;">&#9734;</span> Save</a>
</div>
<div class="Gen">Gen 3</div>
  <div class="ViewMore"><a href="Mini.html">View More</a></div>
    </div>
      </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

(Modal Window)
<div class="modal-body">
        <table class="show-cart table">
            
        </table>
        <div>Total price: £<span class="total-cart"></span></div>
      </div>

Javascript:
function displayCart() {
  var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
  var output = "";
  for(var i in cartArray) {
    output += "<tr>"
      + "<td>< data-img= " + cartArray[i].name + "></td>" 
      + "<td>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" 
      + "<td>(" + cartArray[i].price + ")</td>"
      + "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">-</button>"
      + "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
      + "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">+</button></div></td>"
      + "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">X</button></td>"
      + " = " 
      + "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" 
      +  "</tr>";
  }
  $('.show-cart').html(output);
  $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
  $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
}

// Delete item button

$('.show-cart').on("click", ".delete-item", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
  displayCart();
})


// -1
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
  displayCart();
})
// +1
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
  displayCart();
})

// Item count input
$('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
   var name = $(this).data('name');
   var count = Number($(this).val());
  shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
  displayCart();
});
// image
$('.show-cart').on("click", "img", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
  displayCart();
})

displayCart();

I understand I am missing the element that displays the image in the Javascript, but as mentioned, I know very little about Javascript, and my research has come up with no joy.
This line does display the image name successfully:

"< data-img= " + cartArray[i].name + ">"

Your help is gratefully appreciated
